# cron job for ubuntu to solve apache2 ram problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, apache-httpd, jobs

Sometimes Apache2 keeps generating new processes till the ram is totally consumed and all websites become very very slow.

I wrote a bash file and created a cron job that checks ram usage every minute. If it is over 90% apache2 restarts.

This solved the slowness problem but  is there any dangerous side affects for this solution?

Answer (score 2):

Don't reload/restart your server via cron job. Do you want to restart the server every minute if the server is under load? What happens if the server fails to restart?

You should determine the average size of your Apache processes and how much of your available memory you would like to spend for all Apache processes
and set the `MaxRequestWorkers` (`MaxClients` before Apache2.4) directive accordingly, your current value is too high.

An indicator for the `MaxRequestWorkers` value could be the number of Apache processes when you hit the 90% limit.

From [Apache Performance Tuning - Hardware and Operating System Issues](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html#hardware)

> The single biggest hardware issue affecting webserver performance is RAM. A webserver should never ever have to swap, as swapping
> increases the latency of each request beyond a point that users consider "fast enough". This causes users to hit stop and reload,
> further increasing the load. You can, and should, control the [MaxRequestWorkers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers)
> setting so that your server does not spawn so many children that it starts swapping. The procedure for doing this is simple: **determine
> the size of your average Apache process, by looking at your process list via a tool such as top, and divide this into your total available memory, leaving some room for other processes**.

Further reading:

- [Configuring for Performance](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/misc/perf-scaling.html#configuring-for-performance) (Apache 2.5 Documentation)